# Microsoft Graph filter vs $filter

Tags: microsoft-graph-api

I am testing filtering using [Microsoft Graph Explorer](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/graph-explorer). I noticed odd behavior that I cannot figure out.

Using endpoint `https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/events?filter=start/dateTime%20ge%20%272018-04-01%27` I get properly filtered data back.

However, using documented `$` prefix,  `https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/events?$filter=start/dateTime%20ge%20%272018-04-01%27`, I get nothing. There is no error, just no data coming back.

How do I query the data using the `$filter`?

Answer (score 3):

You're not actually getting the results you think you are. When Microsoft Graph sees a query parameter it doesn't expect, it simply ignores it.

When you call `/events?filter=start/dateTime ge '2018-04-01'` it is simply ignoring the unknown `filter` parameter and returning you an **unfiltered** result.

When you call `/events?filter=start/dateTime ge '2018-04-01'`, it is filtering out anything prior to April 1, 2018. If there are no events with a `start` after this date, you will get an empty array as a result.

I assume you're using the default dataset included with Graph Explorer? The default Graph Explorer data set's most recent `event` is `2017-11-16T08:00:00.0000000`.

The reason you see results from the `/calendarView` endpoint but not the `/events` endpoint is that `/events` only returns single instance meetings and series masters while `/celandarView` shows everything within a date range. In order to avoid having to maintain a dataset with updated events, the demo data relies on a handful of recurring `event` entries.

Since `events` does not return individual occurrences of a meeting, you don't see any results from your query.

If you try this query, you'll see actual results:

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/events?$filter=start/dateTime ge '2017-04-01'
```